# VB 2008 & Debugger?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

using vb.net 2008
When I put a break on a line and then press F5 the debugger does break on the line which I put the Break (F9) but Step In (F8) as well as F5 are grayed out, not working, as well as a bunch of other debug tools. 
Any clue why this is? Is there a setting that needs to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you're running a Release Build. Check if you have a combobox somewhere on your toolbars with the text Release... you should select Debug instead.

If you have trouble finding this toolbar, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because that breakpoint will never be hit because it is not lying in your path of execution?

Make sure that you can `F5` into the entry point ( typically, the `main()` method) and start from there.

Comment: the breakpoint is hit, and it breaks, but then the f5 and f8 are disabled